# Points of $f(x)=x^3$ except the origin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, extreme-value-analysis

I want to know what properties does the non-zero points in the domain of $f(x)=x^3$ have?

For example, $0$ is an inflection point, since the curvature changes sign at $0$ ($f''$ changes sign near $0$). In fact it is an stationary point as well $(f'(0)=0)$. So, it is also a saddle point.

What about if $x\neq 0$. Are these points inflection point or something else? I think such points ($x_0\neq 0$) are not inflection points nor saddle points, since then $f''(x_0)=6x_0\neq 0$ if $x_0\neq 0$.

But from the graph, it seems such points are neither maximum nor minimum points. Can someone please explain in detail what should these non-zero points be called?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ordinary points I guess?

Answer (score 1):

**First Derivative Test:**

A necessary condition for a function $f: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ to have a critical point at $x_0 \in \mathbf{R}$ is that $f'(x_0) = 0$.

Using this test, it is easy to deduce that the only critical point for
$$
f(x) = x^3
$$
is at the origin $x = 0$.

It is easy to verify that $x = 0$ is a saddle point for $f$ since
$$
f''(0) = 0, \ \ f'''(0) \neq 0
$$

The question is about the non-zero points $x \neq 0$.

Obviously they cannot be critical points since $f'$ vanishes only at $x = 0$.

Geometrically, the function $f$ is concave upwards in the region $x > 0$.

The function $f$ is concave downwards in the region $x < 0$.

(The function $f$ changes from concave downwards to concave upwards at $x = 0$.)

[[image: Graph of <span class=]$f(x) = x^3$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTypu.jpg)

Comment: So are these inflection points? Because inflection points are those where the function changes concavity from up to down (or convexity from up to down or vice-versa). But I think these are not inflection points, since at these points the second derivative is non-zero.